# CMake: install(FILES ...) for a file containing a list of files

Tags: cmake

Consider I have a simple text file containing a list of (absolute) file paths.

Is there any easy way to make CMake install those files (as if `install(FILES ...)` was used)?
Directory structure (minus some constant leading path components) should be maintained.

---

Right now the only option I could come up with was to use

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND my_script.sh)")
```

and do it using normal shell commands, but that seems to defeat the purpose of using a build system in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would do the trick:

```
# 'filename' is the file that contains a list ';' separated paths relative to that input file
function(install_my_files filename)
    file(READ ${filename} relative_paths)
    get_filename_component(parent_directory ${filename} DIRECTORY) # parent directory of input file
    foreach(relative_path ${relative_paths})
        get_filename_component(relative_directory ${relative_path} DIRECTORY)
        install(FILES "${parent_directory}/${relative_path}" DESTINATION ${relative_directory})
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

Comment: Thanks! The part `# 'filename' is the file that contains a list ';' separated paths relative to that input file` was actually quite a bit of work, but by calling `execute_process()` a few times with heavy use of `grep`, `sed` and `tr` I got the job done without even needing an intermediate file.